# Retrofit2 response body is null

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I built a Retrofit2 to get a request from https, I have also built a log interceptor with OKHttpClient, the log show the correct result from http get, but response.body() from retrofit is empty, how should I to solve the problem?

```html
HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
      @Override
      public void log(String message) {
        //打印retrofit日志
        Log.i("RetrofitLog","retrofitBack = "+message);
      }
    });
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().client(client).baseUrl(Constant.baseURL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    BannerService bannerService = retrofit.create(BannerService.class);

    Call<JSONObject> bannerResult = bannerService.getBannerList(5);
 
    bannerResult.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>()
    {


      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<JSONObject> call, Response<JSONObject> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
          System.out.println("----------------------\t"+response.body());
        } else {
          // error response, no access to resource?
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<JSONObject> call, Throwable t) {

      }
    });
```

the final interceptor log result is as following:

```
> 
I/RetrofitLog: retrofitBack = Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
I/RetrofitLog: retrofitBack = Content-Length: 1515
               retrofitBack = Connection: keep-alive
               retrofitBack = Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-store
               retrofitBack = Last-Modified: Fri, 15 Jun 2018 03:00:00 GMT
               retrofitBack = Pragma: no-cache
               retrofitBack = X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
               retrofitBack = X-Frame-Options: DENY
               retrofitBack = X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
               retrofitBack = X-Daa-Tunnel: hop_count=2
               retrofitBack = X-NWS-LOG-UUID: 0756741f-5bc5-44ba-9b3e-82dd08ae6f95
               retrofitBack = X-Cache-Lookup: Hit From Upstream
........
> 
> ----------------//here is the correct out------------------
>
>
> I/RetrofitLog: retrofitBack = {"resultModel":[{"banner_id":3,"banner_title":"拾光cafe","banner_description":"合肥工业大学校内的咖啡厅，方便实惠","banner_image_name":"84c61eca-ac3c-4fa3-8146-43cce52aebc3.jpg","banner_create_time":"2018-05-31 12:54:47","banner_creater_id":1000000,"banner_href":"1000000807","enabled":1},{"banner_id":100003,"banner_title":"合肥悦方IDMall · 永辉超市","banner_description":"一个永远都有试吃的超市","banner_image_name":"fe154125-3752-4842-907d-203e45ae51ad.jpg","banner_create_time":"2018-03-26 16:33:45","banner_creater_id":100000000,"banner_href":"http","enabled":1},{"banner_id":100002,"banner_title":"斛兵塘","banner_description":"距今已有一千七百多年历史的一个水塘","banner_image_name":"b4f1281c-e43d-4a69-903f-5e1eb3505938.jpg","banner_create_time":"2018-03-26 16:13:13","banner_creater_id":100000000,"banner_href":"http","enabled":1},{"banner_id":100001,"banner_title":"合肥天鹅湖","banner_description":"一个形状神似天鹅的人工湖","banner_image_name":"1c796d8d-b868-4590-ae0e-d0599ad462cf.jpg","banner_create_time":"2018-03-26 16:10:32","banner_creater_id":100000000,"banner_href":"http","enabled":1},{"banner_id":100000,"banner_title":"合肥工业大学","banner_description":"一个食堂上央视的高校","banner_image_name":"92361818-2daf-45db-9294-d36241fd243b.jpg","banner_create_time":"2018-03-22 10:05:21","banner_creater_id":1000000,"banner_href":"1000000241","enabled":1}],"resultCode":200,"resultMessage":"请求成功"}   
> 
> 
>> ----------------//here is the correct out------------------ 
>
>
> .........
>
>
>
I/System.out: ----------------------    {}   //here is my system.out is empty
>
>
>
> I/Choreographer: Skipped 253 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are mixing up concepts. First you are passing a GsonConverter:

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().client(client).baseUrl(Constant.baseURL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
```

But then your are expecting a JSONObject:

```
 Call<JSONObject> bannerResult = bannerService.getBannerList(5);
```

When passing a GsonConverter Retrofit is converting into Gson and not JSONObject. That means you should declare your own Java pojo with the proper Gson annotations. Example:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

public class Banner {

    @Expose
    public String oneField

    @Expose
    public String otherField;

}
```

As you are expecting a List you sould change your BannerService:

```
public interface BannerService {

    @GET("/your/path/to/get/banner/list")
    Call<List<Banner>> getBannerList(@Path("id") int id);

}
```

And finally change your line to receive the List...

```
 Call<List<Banner>> bannerResult = bannerService.getBannerList(5);
```

and replace your Callback instantiation and methods to receive the List where you where expecting a JSONObject.